# working iframe with jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to do some jquery script using button clicked inside an `iframe` and the output is outside an iframe....Is it possible??? my main html look like this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>    
    <body>    
        <div id="test" >test</div>
        <iframe width="100px" height="100px" src="test.php" ></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

and for test.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.min.js" ></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#btn').click(function(){
                    $('#test').hide(); // i want to hide this whenever a button with id btn inside     and iframe is triggered
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id='btn' >click</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

that's the way I do it but this doesn't work. Thanks for any ideas... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :-

```
$('#test', window.parent.document).hide();
```

Comment: It will work with $("#test",window.parent.document).val(xmlhttp.reponseText);

It is for 'GET' purposes....

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $(window.parent.getElementById('test')).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.parent` if your iframe and your current page are of same domain else it won't work.

Comment: It will work with $("#test",window.parent.document).val(xmlhttp.reponseText);

It is for 'GET' purposes....

Answer (score 0):

#### Try : parent.$('#test').hide();